# How to read the ajax json data in server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have created an ajax request in the client side and pass the data to the server side. issue I face is i cannot read the json object passed in the server side.
here is the client side code segment I used

```
var email=document.forms["login-form"]["email"].value;
var password=document.forms["login-form"]["password"].value;

alert("Innn");

$.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/wcw/wcw/checkuser.php",  
    data: JSON.stringify({email: email ,password: password}),

}).done(function() {

    alert("DONNEEEE");
    window.location.replace("checkuser.php");

});
```

I wanted to read the json data in the server side.

```
$input = $_POST["email"];

$result = json_decode($input);

echo $result;
```

but this will give an error saying

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\wcw\wcw\checkuser.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all, it is saying the index `email` is undefined. Meaning it doesn't exist when you are referencing the index `email` in `$_POST['email']` and that is because of how you set `data`

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/wcw/wcw/checkuser.php",  
    data: {email: email, password: password},
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data)
})
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: Just updated it, try it again and let me know if it works. I removed the json encoding, if you need that refer to the above answer.. if not this should work

Comment: Thanks it reads the object now, but for some reason the  window.location.replace("checkuser.php"); wont work after the changers

Comment: are you seeing the alert? `alert("DONNEEEE");`

Comment: and are you redirecting to the page to see the results of the ajax?

Comment: yes i can see the alert , yeah i want to see the result in the other page. I used firebug to check if the response works properly after doing the changers.

Comment: You cant see the `echo` statements when you redirect because the POST request is not active when you redirect. If you want to POST and see the results use a form with `checkuser.php` as the action and `post` as the method

Comment: or pass data in to `done` callback like I demonstrate in my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

For fetching JSON object from POST,  use `php://input stream wrapper`. Accessing input stream will allow reading the raw request body.

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```